# Oracle: How to do multiple counts with different where clauses the best way?

Tags: oracle, count, where-clause, multiple-columns

I have requirement to count rows with different where clauses from the same table.  The following is the required output from me

```
Bu   #A   #B  #C  #D #E #F #G  #H  #J  #K  #L   #M  #N
GB01 267  284 84  45 35 32 458 801 111 899 892  56  99
NL01 132  844 65  28 26 12 627 321 56  681 1062 127 128
```

Each column has its own criteria, so far I have the following SQL but it already looks ugly and doesn't exactly return what I need

```
SELECT *  FROM (
  SELECT
    c_unit_code,
    COUNT(*) AS ADVICE_EXPORT,
    0 AS CONFIRMATION_EXPORT,
    0 AS ISSUANCE_STANDBY
  FROM EXIMTRX.EPLC_MASTER
  WHERE (CLS_FLG NOT LIKE 'YES' OR CLS_FLG IS NULL) AND (
    form_of_lc LIKE 'IRREVOCABLE' OR
    form_of_lc LIKE 'REVOCABLE' OR
    form_of_lc LIKE 'IRREVOCABLE TRANSFERABLE' OR
    form_of_lc LIKE 'REVOCABLE TRANSFERABLE') AND our_eng LIKE 'ADVICE'
    GROUP BY c_unit_code
UNION
  SELECT
    c_unit_code,
    0 AS ADVICE_EXPORT,
    COUNT(*) AS CONFIRMATION_EXPORT,
    0 AS ISSUANCE_STANDBY
  FROM EXIMTRX.EPLC_MASTER
  WHERE (CLS_FLG NOT LIKE 'YES' OR CLS_FLG IS NULL) AND (
    form_of_lc LIKE 'IRREVOCABLE' OR
    form_of_lc LIKE 'REVOCABLE' OR
    form_of_lc LIKE 'IRREVOCABLE TRANSFERABLE' OR
    form_of_lc LIKE 'REVOCABLE TRANSFERABLE') AND our_eng LIKE 'CONFIRMATION'
    GROUP BY c_unit_code
UNION
  SELECT 
    c_unit_code,
    0 AS ADVICE_EXPORT,
    0 AS CONFIRMATION_EXPORT,
    COUNT(*) AS ISSUANCE_STANDBY
  FROM EXIMTRX.EPLC_MASTER
  WHERE (CLS_FLG NOT LIKE 'YES' OR CLS_FLG IS NULL) AND (
    form_of_lc LIKE 'IRREVOCABLE STANDBY' OR
    form_of_lc LIKE 'REVOCABLE STANDBY' OR
    form_of_lc LIKE 'IRREVOC TRANS STANDBY')
    GROUP BY c_unit_code
);
```

and this is what it returns

```
GB01    0   0   17
GB01    0   39  0
GB01    80  0   0
NL01    0   0   32
NL01    0   159 0
NL01    341 0   0
```

Any ideas, how can I achieve what I need?

Comment: what is the data that you are using it on..??

Comment: Are you sure you want to use LIKE for an exact match? Looks like you need form_of_lc in ('IRREVOCABLE','REVOCABLE','IRREVOCABLE TRANSFERABLE')

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
  SELECT
    c_unit_code,
    COUNT(case when YOUR_CONDITIONS_FOR_ADVICE_EXPORT then 1 end) AS ADVICE_EXPORT,
    COUNT(case when YOUR_CONDITIONS_FOR_CONFIRMATION_EXPORT then 1 end) AS CONFIRMATION_EXPORT,
    COUNT(case when YOUR_CONDITIONS_FOR_ISSUANCE_STANDBY then 1 end) AS ISSUANCE_STANDBY
  FROM EXIMTRX.EPLC_MASTER
  GROUP BY c_unit_code
```